# Combine two index into third index in elastic search using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash, elasticsearch-5

I have two index

1. employee_data
   `{"code":1, "name":xyz, "city":"Mumbai" }`
2. transaction_data
   `{"code":1, "Month":June", payment:78000 }`

I want third index like this
3)join_index

`{"code":1, "name":xyz, "city":"Mumbai", "Month":June", payment:78000 }`
How it's possible??

i am trying in logstash

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localost"
    index => "employees_data,transaction_data"
   
     query => '{ "query": { "match": { "code": 1} } }'
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}
output {
```

elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost"]

```
index => "join1"
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use elasticsearch **input** on *employees_data*

In your filters, use the elasticsearch **filter** on *transaction_data*

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localost"
    index => "employees_data"
   
     query => '{ "query": { "match_all": { } } }'
     sort => "code:desc"

    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}
filter {
    elasticsearch {
              hosts => "localhost"
              index => "transaction_data"
              query => "(code:\"%{[code]}\"
              fields => { 
                    "Month" => "Month",
                    "payment" => "payment" 
                   }
        }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost"]
    index => "join1"
   }
}
```

And send your new document to your third index with the elasticsearch **output**

You'll have 3 elastic search connection and the result can be a little slow.
But it works.

Comment: it is giving me only name ,age and salary

Comment: input {
  elasticsearch {
     
     hosts => ["localhost"]
     index => "employees_data"
     query => '{ "query": { "match_all": { } } }'
  scroll => "5m"
     docinfo => true
  }
}

filter {
 
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost"]
     index => "transaction_data"
     query => '{ "query": { "match": { "code": "1" } } }'
     fields => { "moth" => "month"
                 "payment" => "Payment"
     
                 
               }
  }
 
}

 output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost"]
  index => "join32"
  
       }

}

Comment: transaction data :   
"_index" : "transaction_data",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0lRitXQBbyOi5XzyOfX-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "code" : 1,
          "moth" : "june",
          "payment" : 32080

Comment: Sorry but your comment is very unclear. I guess some fields are missing. You have to declare each fields in the "fields" instruction of your elastic filter https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-fields

Comment: fields => { 
                 "payment" => "payment"
     
                 
               }

Comment: No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort  on is the error

Comment: Ok it's better. By default elasticsearch filter send you the first result of your query order by timestamp. Just add this code and it should work            sort => "code:desc"
 or order it as you want. I just edited my answer

Comment: @Abhishek if the answer helps you please validate and upvote

Comment: is there any way to filter only index just like in employees_data i want to filter out records from city like city :mumbai

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097516/how-to-filter-out-records-based-on-one-param-from-one-index-in-logstash

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Logstash to do this, Elasticsearch itself supports that by leveraging the [`enrich processor`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html).

First, you need to create an enrich policy (use the smallest index, let's say it's `employees_data` ):

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/employee-policy
{
  "match": {
    "indices": "employees_data",
    "match_field": "code",
    "enrich_fields": ["name", "city"]
  }
}
```

Then you can execute that policy in order to create an enrichment index

```
POST /_enrich/policy/employee-policy/_execute
```

When the enrichment index has been created and populated, the next step requires you to create an ingest pipeline that uses the above enrich policy/index:

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/employee_lookup
{
  "description" : "Enriching transactions with employee data",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "enrich" : {
        "policy_name": "employee-policy",
        "field" : "code",
        "target_field": "tmp",
        "max_matches": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "if": "ctx.tmp != null",
        "source": "ctx.putAll(ctx.tmp); ctx.remove('tmp');"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, you're now ready to create your target index with the joined data. Simply leverage the `_reindex` API combined with the ingest pipeline we've just created:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "transaction_data"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "join1",
    "pipeline": "employee_lookup"
  }
}
```

After running this, the `join1` index will contain exactly what you need, for instance:

```
  {
    "_index" : "join1",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "0uA8dXMBU9tMsBeoajlw",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "code":1, 
      "name": "xyz", 
      "city": "Mumbai", 
      "Month": "June", 
      "payment": 78000 
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks val i really aprreciate your approach but i want to do it from logstash

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear it had to be through Logstash. But fine, then what @Jaycreation suggests is one way to go...

Comment: @Val could you explain `tmp` in your pipeline?

Comment: @Marc it's the target field of the `employee-policy` enrich processor

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, this can not be happened just using elasticsearch APIs. To handle this, you need to set a unique ID for documents that are relevant. For example, the code that you mentioned in your question can be a good ID for documents. So you can reindex the first index to the third one and use UPDATE API to update them by reading documents from the second index and update them by their IDs into the third index. I hope I could help.

Comment: actually i am trying it with logstash elastic search