# How to filter out records based on one param from one index in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
input{
 elasticsearch{
  hosts=>["localhost"]
  index=>"sample_index"
    query=>'{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'
scroll=>"5m"
docinfo=>true
 }
 }filter{
 elasticsearch{
 hosts=>["localhost"]
 index=>"sample_index"
 query=>"NOT(city:delhi)"
   sort=>"code:asc"
  result_size=>5    
   fields=>{
   "code"=>"Code"
  "name"=>"Name"
 "city"=>"City"
"salary"=>"Salary"
}
}
}
output{
elasticsearch{
hosts=>["localhost"]
 index=>"filter_sample_index4"
   }
  }
```

This is the way i am doing. Can anyone figure it out where i am doing wrong

Supppose i have records `{ "sample_index":{ "name":"ABC", "salary":56000, "city":"mumbai" }, { "name":"XYZ", "salary":54400, "city":"DEHI" }, { "name":"QWERTY", "salary":65000, "city":"Delhi" }, { "name":"JACK", "salary":26000, "city":"mumbai" }    }`

What i want is this based on city filter out the index `{
"filter_index":{
"name":"ABC",
"salary":56000,
"city":"mumbai"
},

{
"name":"JACK",
"salary":26000,
"city":"mumbai"
}
}`

Comment: Can you please reformat your config, it is not legible as it is. Also please explain what you need, maybe by providing an example. Help us help you!

Comment: @val Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `query` parameter uses the [`query_string` query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax), you can simply invert the query like this:

```
query => "NOT(city:mumbai)"
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error? If yes, which one? Can you describe what behavior you observe and what you expect instead?

Comment: its giving me all records

Comment: What happens if you run this in Kibana Dev Tools `GET sample_index/_search?q=NOT(city:mumbai)` ? What records do you get?

Comment: In kibana dev tools its working perfectly fine but in logstash query param its creating new index but with all records

Comment: Well, the thing is that the `elasticsearch` filter will not exclude records from the `elasticsearch` input. How does your input look like? Can you add that and **please properly format your config**?

Comment: please check !!

Comment: Please re-read my comment and add the **`input` configuration too**!!

Comment: added the input

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that you have `query=>'{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'` in your input, hence why all records come true. You need to restrict which records you want to join in the input not in the filter.

Comment: what if i removed it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222167/discussion-between-abhishek-and-val).

Comment: Removing the condition = `match_all`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981299/how-to-get-kibana-scripted-fields-in-es2csv-5-x