# joining index using multiple index in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to create new index from 3 input index based on common id field. first i am trying to combine 2 index with below code.
And output index generated with the fields in index1,index2. But it is making entry for unmatched records in index2 also. Could someone assit on this.

```
index1:
{index1refId:123, address:"myaddr"
index1refId:124, address:"myaddr4"
}
index2:
{refId:123, name:"myname", sal:34.4, date:"2021"
refId:125, name:"myname5", sal:345.4, date:"2021"
}
index3:
{ref3Id:123, dob:"2000"}
Expecting new joined index:
{refID:123, name:"myname", sal:34.4, date:"2021", address:"myaddr",dob:"2000"}
```

```
input{
   elasticsearch{
   hosts => "hostname"
   index => "index1"
   query => '{"query": {"match_all":{}}}' 
   docinfo => true
   user => "uname"
   password => "pwd"
   ssl => true
 }
}
filter{
   elasticsearch{
     hosts =>"hostname"
     enable_sort => false
     index => "index2"
     user => "uname"
     password => "pwd"
     query_template => "query_template_forindex.json" 
     fields => {
      "name" => "name"
      "sal" => "sal"
      "date" => "date" 
      }
      }
 }
output{
  elasticsearch{
     hosts => "hostname"
     index => "newindex"
     user => "uname"
     password => "pwd"
     doc_as_upsert => true
     document_id => "%{index1refId}"
     ssl => true 
 }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls check below post, hope it helps!!!

The ideal solution will be using an Enrichment processor, which worked out for me in past given by Val.

[Enrichment Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html)

[combine-two-index-into-third-index-in-elastic-search-using-logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008094/combine-two-index-into-third-index-in-elastic-search-using-logstash)

logstash conf file-

```html
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localost"
    index => "employees_data"
   
     query => '{ "query": { "match_all": { } } }'
     sort => "code:desc"

    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}
filter {
    elasticsearch {
              hosts => "localhost"
              index => "transaction_data"
              query => "(code:\"%{[code]}\"
              fields => { 
                    "Month" => "Month",
                    "payment" => "payment" 
                   }
        }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost"]
    index => "join1"
   }
}
```

Comment: i need to join index in logstash, not using Elasticsearch